# Custom Entity Not Showing in View Creation UI

Tags: views, entities, 8

I started learning Drupal 8 this week. I followed [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2192175) to create a new entity, which I then made available through REST using the following tutorial: https://drupalize.me/blog/201401/introduction-restful-web-services-drupal-8

CRUD operations on my entity work just fine. I can also issue my REST requests without any issues. What I'm trying to do now is fetch a list of all my entities via REST. From my understanding, I should create a view for that, but my entity doesn't show up in the view creation UI, so I can't. What do I have to do to make my entity show up there?

I'm not sure what code I should post, so don't hesitate to tell me what code you need to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a views_data handler, like this:

```
"views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData"
```

That exposes your entity as views data.

That is the default implementation, which does a lot, but you might need to subclass that and extend the definitions if you need additional filters/fields/...